# AngularJS – submit data to a new url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am an AngularJS starter. I am trying to redirect user to a new page [Update: It's a completely new page, could be an external url] with data when user clicked a button.

With jQuery, in the click handler function, I could build a form programmatically, and then added the  fields, and then submit the form to the new URL.

```
var form$ = $('<form></form>').attr('action', 'http://example.com/test').attr('method', 'post');
var input$ = $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', aName).attr('value', aValue);
form$.append(input$);
form$.appendTo('body').submit();
```

Is there an Angular way to achieve this?

Comment: Define `new page`. Using an angular router allows you to have infinite routes within one single page app and store data in service to use on a newly loaded route. Or...is this a complete page reload based on form `action`?

Comment: It's a completely new page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`angular.element()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is a subset of jQuery methods that actually uses full jQuery library if jQuery.js is included in page before angular.js.

Without having jQuery it already includes all the methods shown so you should be able to do the same thing by simply replacing `$` with `angular.element` and some minor tweaks.

It is more limited however on selectors you can use to select elements in dom

```
var form$ = angular.element('<form></form>').attr('action', 'http://example.com/test').attr('method', 'post');
var input$ = angular.element('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', aName).val( aValue);
form$.append(input$);
angular.element(document).find('body').append(form$);
form$[0].submit();
```